# Comparing P-Values of two tests doing the same task

Tags: statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, anderson-darling-test

There are two statistical tests which do the same thing. For instance, they both tell if two samples are generated from same distribution. KS Test (2 samples) and Anderson Darling Test (K Samples).

I get two p-values against two samples. KS Test tells me that both come different distribution with p-Value (0.010845160139203348) whereas Anderson tells me the same thing with p-Value (0.004211850196343514).

They both conclude the same decision. However, for one, the P-Value is way too small, that means it more strongly believes that both samples come from different distributions. Could we say that?

Can we draw a conclusion that one test is more powerfull than the other based upon p-values of two tests doing the same comparison?

Comment: Absolutely not, p-values do not measure "power" of a test.

Comment: What could be the way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Distinguish what? What are you trying to achieve? These two tests are different, they have different assumptions and different methodologies, so it is expected that the results differ, although one might except similar results (accept-reject). You already know that, so why are you trying to compare these two tests?